# Free screen capture tool that has decent annotation

Tags: software-recommendation, screen-capture

I'm looking for a free screen capture tool that has decent annotation.  I want to be able to do the following:

- Highlight an area
- Dim everything but the selected area
- Draw arrows
- Blur selected areas

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded the [Snagit Beta for Mac](http://www.techsmith.com/snagitmac/), free for now, I'm sure it will cost when it comes out of beta.  So far it has everything I was asking for except the dimming feature.  It has a few other nice features as well.

Comment: +1,Snagit is fantastic, and the Mac beta is currently *free*.

Answer (score 2):

[LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) (not free)  from Realmac Software does these things plus it has organizing features and web capture features, with source code.

It's more suitable for web or other type of designers, perhaps, but it has these annotation features.

A free tool for fast annotation (although I don't think it has darkening or blurring) is [Skitch](http://skitch.com/) (mentioned by others here as well) which is otherwise very convenient for fast operation.

Answer (score 1):

[Voila](http://www.globaldelight.com/voila/voila_overview.html) can apparently do all that but it’s not free.

[Skitch](http://skitch.com/) i use most of the time to add arrows and such. Very good.

Comment: Voila looks like it might be worth the money.  It captures screen recordings as well.  I may have to purchase it, I'll update if I do.

Answer (score 0):

I second [Skitch](http://skitch.com/). I use it every day. It's free, for now.

Answer (score 0):

[Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) also does much of what you're looking for.